# While compiling 32 bit binary on 64 bit Linux (ubuntu 14.04) getting wrong ELF class error "wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64"

Tags: linux, gcc, chroot

I have 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my system. For some reasons i have to change root directory to a directory which is nothing but a replica of a different system with the required libraries installed which are required for my compilation task.

I have made the directory as root directory with chroot. Now while compiling the 32 bit binary for android which requires `libc++.so` file for compilation it produces the error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

File output of the .so file:

```
$file /cpa/android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt

/cpa/android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=cfb63b4ad11d0c2d59f10329f0116706e99bf72e, not stripped
```

Compiling the binaries for android.

Comment: What's the command you use for compilation?

Comment: The package which I have to compile has a python script file to run which internally makes call to other shell scripts.

the command which i can see in one of the shell script is 

run_cmake -c $CONFIG $WORKSPACE/$path ${!TARGET} -- ${COMMON_OPTS} ${!OPTS} "-DPRODUCT_NAME=${PRODUCT_NAME}"

Comment: What is your LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/:/cpa/android/sdk/platform-tools/lib64/:/lib" Also forgot to add the binary which i am compiling is an android one

Comment: Welcome to U&L please edit [your question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/428433/edit) to add the additional information

Comment: Changes Done!!!